# call a web service from T-SQL in Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, web-services, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to call a HTTP web service from T-SQL (no SQLCLR) in Sql Server 2008?  I just need to send information out, I do not need to receive anything into T-SQL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can automate the `XMLHTTP` server object using the Object Automation extended stored procedures.

[Example here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/validate-a-url-from-sql-server.aspx)

I suggest you use the CLR or an SSIS package though.

Answer (score 2):

The Web Service Task should allow you to do that.

1. [Web Service Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140114.aspx)
2. [How to: Call a Web Service by Using the Web Service Task (SQL Server Video)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc952927%28SQL.100%29.aspx)

I'm assuming you are doing this from an "intergration services" package

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing this in a sproc, then you could create a tiny VB program and use

```
exec sp_cmdshell 'c:\path\myapp.exe'
```

to call your program. Technically its not CLR embedded in SQL Server right? :)